# how to manage CPU resources

Tags: java, multithreading

In a producing and consuming application, let's say producting takes one cpu cycle and consuming takes 3 avarage cpu cycles. Then how do we manage to keep equal number of productions and consumptions boundry. this is a problem I imaginge while I was studying threads.

If you have any idea to implement this with Java please share your knoweledge.

Comment: Have you looked at BlockingQueue? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: Concurrency is a complicated subject, it's not just a matter of CPU cycles, take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581575/system-not-scaling-to-support-concurrent-users/13583213#13583213 and I'd suggest reading the book I recommend there.

Answer (score 3):

You have to design your system so that you consumers can keep up with your producer in the long run.  Most producers are bursty and if you use a queue it doesn't matter that for very short periods they are producing faster than your can consume.  If this is not the case you can

- have multiple consumers.
- drop or combine produced messages to reduce the load on the consumer.
- push back on the producer to slow down.